# Compiler Error(message) while debugging code for automation testing using gherkins and flutter_driver

Tags: automated-tests, flutter-test

When i use command: `dart test_driver/app_test.dart`
I am getting below error:

> file:///D:/jp/flutter_windows_v1.4.9-dev/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/gherkin-1.1.1/lib/src/gherkin/parameters/string_parameter.dart:5:46:
>   Error: No named parameter with the name 'dotAll'.
>         : super(name, RegExp("'\"['\"]", dotAll: true),
>                                                ^^^^^^ org-dartlang-sdk:///runtime/lib/regexp_patch.dart:10:11: Context:
>   Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.   factory
>   RegExp(String source,

Answer (score 0):

Check that your dart is not older than the dart that flutter uses.

```
dart --version
```

If It is just run:

```
brew upgrade dart
```